# Mocking JavascriptSerializer results in error

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Hi I have created a wrapper over the JavascriptSerializer to be able to moq this.

This is my code:

```
public class JavascriptSerializerWrapper : IJavascriptSerializerWrapper
{
    public JavaScriptSerializer GetJavascriptSerializer()
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer();
    }
}
```

Now in my unit tests I have tryed to mock this like this:

```
    private Mock<IJavascriptSerializerWrapper> m_JavascriptSerializerWrapper;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initializer()
    {
        m_JavascriptSerializerWrapper = new Mock<IJavascriptSerializerWrapper>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Login_IsValidUser_ReturnsTrue()
    {
        const string serializedObject = "{\"EmailAddress\":\"kimmiem30@hotmail.com123\",\"StudentId\":1200528,\"TeacherId\":null,\"EmployeeId\":null,\"PersonId\":82249,\"MessageUserId\":410335}";
         m_JavascriptSerializerWrapper.Setup(x => x.GetJavascriptSerializer().Serialize(userInfoDTO)).Returns(serializedObject);
    }
```

I have debugged the unit test and I got this error:

> Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x => x.GetJavascriptSerializer().Serialize(.userInfoDTO)

What am I doing wrong here and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292287.aspx) is not virtual so cannot be mocked. Instead your wrapper interface and class should contain a `Serialize` method which you can mock.

For example:

```
public class JavascriptSerializerWrapper : IJavascriptSerializerWrapper
{
    public string Serialize(object toSerialize)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(toSerialize);
    }
}
```

Then your test can use it like so:

```
m_JavascriptSerializerWrapper.Setup(x => x.Serialize(userInfoDTO)).Returns(serializedObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x.GetJavascriptSerializer().Serialize(userInfoDTO)
```

So you're not just trying to mock the 'IJavascriptSerializerWrapper' but also the JavascriptSerializer itself

What you want is something like:

```
public class JavascriptSerializerWrapper : IJavascriptSerializerWrapper
{
    private JavascriptSerializer _serializer = new JavascriptSerializer();
    public JavaScriptSerializer Serialize()
    {
        return _serializer.Serialize();
    }
}
```